# How strong is Battle Cat?

Tags: he-man

I watched the He-Man 1983 series when I was a kid, in 1986. Later, I watched some episodes again while an adult. I’ve never watched the 2002 series or read the comics; the only other He-Man I've seen is the 80's live action movie.

I remember from the 80's cartoon He-Man was strong enough to move a moon or lift Castle GraySkull. With his sword he used to turn Cringer into a larger animal called Battle Cat, so he made him stronger. But how strong was Battle Cat? Just as strong as a tiger who has doubled in size, or did he have superhero-like strength close to that of He-Man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Battle Cat has strength comparable to He-Man

[According to he-man.org](http://old.he-man.org/cartoon/cmotu/behindthescenes/ahhpowertoo.shtml), the original plans for the iconic transformation scene called for Adam/He-Man's shouts of "By the power of Grayskull!" and "I have the power!" to be followed by Battle Cat saying **"Ahh! And I have the power, too!"**:

[image: Storyboard frame featuring Battle Cat's transformation]

The article mentions that this plan made it past the design phase and into production: Battle Cat's mouth movements in the final animation match the pronunciation of this line even though the audio was replaced with a roar.

The power of Grayskull manifests in He-Man as strength and endurance.  Since Battle Cat declares that he has the same power as He-Man, their strength is on the same supernatural level.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that we ever see Battle Cat do anything much more significant than carry He-Man. The implication was (especially in the 80's cartoon) that Cringer's transformation into Battle Cat was more about getting the armor/saddle and some courage. Here's the full backstory of the character. You'll note it heavily focuses on Cringer (Battle Cat doesn't even appear until 15:43), and when Battle Cat does come in, the Sorceress notes that he probably shouldn't call him Cringer in that form.

Answer (score 0):

If you take into account masters of the universe revelation, after transformation Adam can share the power with Cringer and Skeletor. When doing this he brings Skeletor back to his uplifted form with power similar to Adam's uplifted form as shown in their final battle.
So there is no reason to doubt that Cringers uplifted form as Battle Cat has less power than if he used the sword himself. So Yes, if you take account of something canonical made 4 years after your question... Battle Cat shares the same power as He-Man and has the same potential. The only difference is that Adam has the sword and is a "better user" of this power than Cringer.

Comment: Why is there no reason to doubt it? Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold statements?

Comment: Because he restores Skeletor to the god form in the same move that he turns Cringer into Battle Cat. This implies that he is using the sword to give "the power" to them also. This might indicate that Batle Cat is the uplifted form of Cringer, the same as Skelegod is from Skeletor and He-Ma is the Adam's uplifted form. So he has the same power potential as the others, the difference is the way he uses the power.

Comment: That they've received some power is not in dispute. Are you saying that having 'the power' makes you identically strong to everyone else with it?

Comment: That is why I said he shares the same power and have the same potential. The user's skill to use the power still counts. Skeletor tries to lock in an infinite battle with He-Man and it seems that Skelegod and He-Man had the same brute strength, but He-Man using his skill could go around brute force. I imagine that is the same situation between Batle Cat and other users of "the power"

Comment: And in the end it is a Kid's show, there is not many PG13 ways to show that a Feline is strong, Unless you put something for him to carry or pull... They won't put on screen a super claw or super bite =)